# Bezier curves of an iris.

Tags: calculus

I've got rather limited math background, having never taken a calculus class. I'm trying to program an iris, and I've got little clue where to start. I know I'm dealing with arcs, and that the angle of the center of the iris never changes, but I'm not sure what else needs to be done.

This is Apple's implementation of what I want to accomplish: http://youtu.be/ZX8nnCR4VyM I *think* I need to put plot control points against the "radius" of the inner octagon, but I'm not sure.

Where can I start?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to specify the curve that represents the edges of the iris.  The easiest is straight lines, which is not what is shown in the link.  The selection of the curve is dependent on what your purpose is.  For photographic applications, you want the out of focus elements to look nice.  For many computer applications, straight lines are fine.  Then you can find much on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octagon#Regular_octagon).  The lines are either horizontal, vertical, of of slope $\pm1$ through the points.